# Batch File calls VBScript which calls EXE that won't open

Tags: windows, scripting, vbscript, batch-file

I have a VBS file 'migration.vbs' that runs a number of commands and then calls an AutoIt .exe file to begin the uninstall of a product. The entire script runs successfully when you call it by itself from the command line with 'cscript migration.vbs'

This script is going to be pushed out to a number of other machines where techs need to be able to double-click to run it. A lot of the machines don't execute VBS by default on a double click, so I've added a batch file to run it.

The problem is that when the batch file calls the VBS, it starts to run but never calls the exe. It just.. skips that step. I'm guessing there's an issue with nested system calls or something that I don't know about.

Anyways, any solutions? I'd rather not put the EXE call in the batch file due to logic checking the VBS does against registry keys (that'd be hard/impossible to duplicate in BAT).

Thanks again

start.bat

```
START /WAIT cscript .\data\migration.vbs
```

migration.vbs

```
WSHSHell.Run "uninstall.exe", 0, True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no nested system calls limit, I'm guessing that the path or current directory is wrong, try using a full path or monitor the filesystem calls with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)

Comment: Interesting. The path was the answer. Apparently the working directory for the VBscript was set to the working directory of the batch file, despite them being in separate directories.